# How can I import a component directly instead of from the root index file?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules

I wrote myself a small package which I use to share different React components between my projects.

The "exports" field in my package.json looks like this:
Since this is a TypeScript project, the transpiled .js in the output directory are specified below.

```json
"exports": {
    ".": "./lib/index.js"
  }
```

My index.ts file looks like this:

```ts
export * from "./Grids";
```

Then inside my Grids folder i have another index.ts file with the following content:

```ts
export * from "./UniversalGrid";
```

And finally inside the UniversalGrid folder, there is another index.ts file, in which the actual components is getting exported:

```ts
export * from "./UniversalGrid";
```

Now when I want to use the component in my app, I am shown two import suggestions, namely:

```ts
import {UniversalGrid} from "@privateComponents/react-components"
```

and

```ts
import {UniversalGrid} from "@privateComponents/react-components/lib/Grids/UniversalGrid"
```

The first approach (import from /react-components), works without problems.

However, with the second possible import statement (import from /react-components/lib/Grids/UniversalGrid) the following occurs:

```
Module not found: Error: Package path ./lib/Grids/UniversalGrid is not exported from package C:\Users\<user>\WebstormProjects\PKD\node_modules\@privateComponents\react-components
```

However, this way the component can be imported without any problems, and also when I select "Jump to definition" I am led to the correct file.

Now I have two questions, first, why is this happening?

And second, how can I import/export my components separately.

Say: Grid1 should be imported from  `/Grids/Grid1`.

Grid 2 should be imported from `/Grids/Grid2`.

But none of the modules should be imported directly from the /Grids folder.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just dont export Grid in Grids/index.ts, change your transpiled to this

```
  "exports": {
    ".": "./lib/index.js",
    "./Grids/Grid1": "./lib/Grids/Grid1/index.js",
    "./Grids/Grid2": "./lib/Grids/Grid2/index.js"
    ...
  },
```

Now you can import Grid1 from /Grids/Grid1 not from /Grids